# Approval Process Workflow in an ERP system

Tags: node.js, workflow, erp

I am trying to develop an approval process workflow for a module of an ERP system. Before storing the values from an html form to mysql database an approval mail is sent to approvers and after that the status is being updated as approved in the module database. How to develop program for approval workflow. Preferably in nodejs.

I tried finding on AI tools the solution for the same and got nodemailer to send mail. But after mailing through sample email ids on gmail the mail is not sent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.